# Sprint Boot: IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry

Tags: java, spring-boot, nested, illegalstateexception

I know that problems with nested jar files in connection to fat jars are common and I found a lot of questions about this here. I understand the reason what the problem is for Spring to run the jar file. Checking the resulting jar file showed that the actual application classes are not present. Unfortunately, I still do not get why I actually do experience this problem and how to fix it.

First of all, the exception I get when trying to run my fat jar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar'. It has been
compressed and nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechanism used to create your executable jar file
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:285)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:248)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>funky.PrimeCalculator</groupId>
<artifactId>PrimeCalculator</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <start-class>funky.app.Main</start-class>
</properties>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<name>PrimeCalculator</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- AspectJ (required spring-aop dependency) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Remove the shade and compiler plugin plugin, spring boot takes care of all that. Also the shade plugin is now competing with the spring boot plugin to create a jar. Also stop mixing versions of frameworks (spring boot 1.4.2 and 1.4.3) and I strongly suggest the use of `spring-boot-starter-aop` instead of manually trying to find the jars.

Comment: Thank you, I made the changes you mentioned and edited the original post. The exception from above is gone, I still have no classes inside my pom.xml, but I guess this is a totally different topic.

Comment: Why would you need classes in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: Sorry, a typo. I have (had) no classes in my jar file because the project structure is not in accordance to maven's standard layout.